# Add button to WooCommerce orders table

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a custom button to my WooCommerce orders.php file. At the moment I'm doing this with adding the button directly to the orders.php file which is not so good because of updates and overwriting. This is how it looks at the moment:

[image]

---

This is my code:

```
echo '<a href="" class="woocommerce-button button red no-arrow margin-right">' . get_option( 'custom_button_text' ) . '</a>';
```

Do you know how I can add this to the orders.php with a hook? I've checked out the page and found no near hook. Is there a better way to replace the whole site?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I am sure there will be a hook for this. Look into WooCommerce hooks. You are correct in the assumption that an update will, correctly, overwrite your edits.

Comment: @rockhopper72 Forgot it, Im sorry. To tired.